# Howto load an external html form into Simplemodal OSX style dialog

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Thanks for your jquery plug in. I know howto load an external html page into a simplemodal dialog with this code :

```
var src = "form.html";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="430" width="510" style="border:0">', {
closeHTML:"",
containerCss:{
    backgroundColor:"#ffa",
    borderColor:"#ffa",
    height:350,
    padding:0,
    width:530
},
overlayClose:true
});
```

I would like to do the same thing with simplemodal osx style.
Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Thibault

Comment: lol @ Hello Eric

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Eric, but this should allow you to omit the iframe and use whatever styling you want (not sure what OS X style is — a theme, maybe?):

```
$.get('form.html', function(response) {
  $.modal(response, {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{
      backgroundColor:"#ffa",
      borderColor:"#ffa",
      height:350,
      padding:0,
      width:530
    },
    overlayClose:true
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can get this result already in a simplemodal dialog. I would to have my external form in a OSX style dialog. Here you can see an osx style exemple : http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: I realize that this solution shouldn't look any different than what you have already. This way you can apply any styling to to the loaded content by using already loaded styles. What comes to the `OS X` style — you'll have to be much more specific on what you're after or what your problem is.

Comment: I know this is an old question. I'm using eric's osx-style-dialog for my project. I want to know how to change the width of the window

Answer (score 0):

So after taking a look at simplemodal and more specifically the OSX example, it appears to be built using prototype and not jQuery (that's what the simplemodal website says). Why wouldn't you use prototype add in the external form? What problem exactly are you having? Is the modal not working or is the form not being added to it? or is there an additional issue? Specifics would help.